# opening a flip book on lightbox popup

Tags: php, jquery, css

i have a popup lightbox i want to open a jquery css flipbook but the thing is the page is not getting loaded.

Ex : I have a page with a link to popup. On clicking on this link the popup window will open a  file which is located in a different file say xyz/test.php .

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="flipbook/index.html" data-lightbox="example-1">Chandelier</a><br><br>`enter code here`
```

The lightbox opens but the flipbook page content doesn't gets loaded.

Comment: can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zuad/T5ZYh/